# Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have written a fancy heat graph with javascript & raphael and it worked great and flawlessly. Now, three months after I completed the task and went on to other pastures, I get this error:

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute
```

...with a particular snippet of code in the leading instance indicating where this error is taking place.  (Yes the error lists itself about 500+ times but only the leading instance gives the line of code where the error takes place.)

I looked around and found nothing substantial leading me to a solution.  So, I managed to remove the code listed in the leading instance, hoping that would solve the problem. And as is always the case, it propagates to another line of code, this time in the Raphael.js code...

How does one troubleshoot that??  I don't want to fix the Raphael code, if I don't have to...  Any help would be appreciated.

More code

```
function todayBand(){
    // Band which represents *TODAY*
    for (var i=2; i<47; i++){
        xx = parseInt(calcOffset+i*hour_millis/(2*timeZoom)); x2 =  xOff(xx-100,220);           
        pp = "p_"+i;
        window[pp] = paper.path("M "+xx+" 350 l "+x2+" -220 z").attr("stroke", "#999").toBack();   //PRESENT TIME LINE IN RED
        window[pp].class="paths";
        paper.path("M "+xx+" 350 l 0 15 z").attr("stroke", "#aaa" ).toBack();   //PRESENT TIME LINE IN RED
    }
}
```

TIA

Dennis

Comment: Hard to help if you post 0 lines of code. You troubleshoot it by examining the stack trace at the time the error happens. Add a breakpoint and figure out which parameter is incorrectly passed

Comment: It didn't give you a line number?

Comment: Nan Stands for "Not a Number" this usually occurs when you are trying to do math with a string or char. you could try parseINT before you use the variable

Comment: I believe that it's a bad path.  Output the paths to console.log, and I bet that you'll find the problem.

Comment: The code is perfectly good... here it is "pp = "p_"+i;"   and it is perfectly good an valid code in Javascript

Comment: I am constructing a variable dynamically, iterating with the i variable going from 2 to 47...  so I would get p_2 variable, p_3, p_4...   etc!

Comment: Jonathan, I know where the code is, but there is nothing wrong with the code!

Comment: It must be misdirecting me as to where the problem is really taking place

Comment: @GeenGiant, maybe you have some point here.  I am mixing character and integer to create a new variable.  But it worked great until last Friday!  "pp = "p_"+i;"

Comment: console.log is your friend.  I seriously doubt that the issue is in the Raphael code.  I still think that it is in your data that you are passing to Raphael.  I base this off of similar experience using Raphael.

Comment: still can't help with no code posted...perhaps you are using a `for..in` loop on an array or something, and you have a framework (like prototype) prototyping extra stuff to the array object?

Comment: @CM Kanode How do you output the path to the console???

Comment: @DennisKean console.log(yourVariable);  Note: using IE, you must have the developers tools open for console to exist.  For Chrome and FF, it is present.  As much as I hate to say it, IE has pretty good developers tools.  Hit F12 to activate, and click "start debugging".

Comment: Here is more code for you... I added the code in the original frame!

Comment: @DennisKean please edit your question and add your code there.  Please format it, too, to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Crayon Violent  Look at the original frame for more code!

Comment: where is `timeZoom` being set? I wonder if it is being set to 0 (or not set at all? Same with your other vars, but importantly `timeZoom` since that would result in a division by 0

Comment: TimeZoom isa a global var
   But I can check it... to see if it is set!

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I see how this works.  It is reporting the wrong line for error.  I stepped through Raphael and it seems to fail on a line way below the one it indicates...  So, I will go fishing there.  I just don't know who to credit.  You all have given me an idea a piece.  How can I give credit to several people for the help, here???

Comment: @Crayon Violent  ... Ah...thank you.  I did not realize that it was an issue.  Many thanks for your help...

Comment: Well, I found the solution...  Passing a null or an empty value when a numeric value is required, to Raphael, will cause this problem.  But it will not return the error until the last stack call is released.  Then it finds the time to insert the error code line.  But by then you are miles from the real position of the error.

Comment: POSSIBLE ANSWER (my 'answer' will apply to only a small subset of people) ... ... I am using Raphael-2.1.1 along with raphael.free_transform.js ... ... like the OP, my app worked fine and then _all of the sudden_ it started producing this same error ... ... a couple of days ago I changed my Raphael constructor from `Raphael(my_div)` to `Raphael(my_div,'100%','100%')` ... ... it is the stringiness of those 100's that seems to be messing up things ... ... So I used some jquery to get numerical pixel values for `Raphael(my_div,345,510)` ... ... the strings led to the `null` values.